# ohlc chart in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

Is there a way to detect when the mouse goes over a bar in the chart ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ImageMapUtilities](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/imagemap/ImageMapUtilities.html). I added mouseover capabilities by drawing custom [XYAnnotations](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/AbstractXYAnnotation.html) over what I wanted the browser to respond to, and specifying the appropriate tooltip/URLs in the annotation.

(the above is particularly useful for a browser)